# Парсинг XML через регулярные выражения

Tags: java, xml, парсер

Интересует документация/книги в которых освещается вопрос парсинга XML с помощью регулярных выражений.

Имеется статический XML-документ, структура не изменяется.

Кто сталкивался, будем признательны за материал.

**P.S. Парсеры не советовать. Интересуют именно регулярные выражения**

Comment: а зачем это делать регулярками?

Comment: С целью самообразования и повышения навыков

Comment: Можешь тут посмотреть: https://regex101.com/library?orderBy=RELEVANCE&search=xml

Comment: Если структура известна и не меняется, то может есть смысл сразу мэппить на класс? Парсить регуляркой XML/HTML для самообразования - не самая лучшая идея, есть много готовых решений, как это сделать быстрее и эффективнее. Если хочется поиграться с регулярками, то есть смысл парсить сложные URL или текст, это с большей вероятностью пригодится в жизни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[image: ah shit]
[Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) есть развернутый ответ на ваш вопрос. Для общего случая он очень даже верен. Пусть английский язык вас не пугает, там достаточно будет набора слов, используемых в языках программирования, чтобы понять посыл.

Если вам надо вытащить из большой xml-ки конкретную вещь, в принципе, можно сделать это с помощью регулярки, но оно того не особо стоит, как правило. Если, конечно, вы не используете сам xml не для того, для чего он был создан. Опишите конкретнее задачу, если хотите получить более вразумительный ответ

PS Если вам нужно что угодно, только не парсер, то зачем добавлять тег "парсер"?

Comment: У меня имеются xml-файлы, которые создаются периодически. Теги внутри одинаковые, а вот текст всегда может быть какой угодно. Мне нужно получить все теги этого файла для анализа и, соответственно, текст который содержится внутри тегов. Но, понятное дело, текст есть не во всех тегах.

Comment: Если вы абсолютно уверены, что у вас глубина тегов не более 1, то можно регуляркой получить список тегов, думается. Но ассоциировать тэг<->текст в этом теге вы не сможете. То есть сделать  такое реально, но запрашивая регуляркой из большого файла что-то подстроку вида "<tag>текст произвольной немаленькой длинны</tag>" вы можете получить задачу очень высокой сложности из-за особенностей из-за особенностей регулярок. Проще найти поиском <tag> и </tag> и, зная начальный и конечный индекс, получить substring.

Comment: Звучит так, как будто этот xml - файл с настройками, где тэг - параметр, а внутри тегов хранятся значения параметра. Крайне не рекомендую так использовать xml, он не для того создан